# Activate a TextArea by typing a <newline>

Tags: codenameone

How can I make a com.codename1.ui.TextArea that will activate when a newline is typed?
I'm trying to create a simple pop-up that will collect a line of text.
[image]

Comment: I don't follow? When will something be typed on random. Most of the devices have VKBs which are folded.

Comment: I have a pop up where you type something.  It’s in response to a pull down menu, so it’s embedded in a small form with an Ok button.  It would be preferable if the ok button was unnecessary.

Comment: I don't understand that explanation. A screenshot and code snippet would go a long way to explain your scenario

Comment: I added a snapshot to the main post.  The user types a name and hits the OK button. But the default behavior of TextField is that if he types a name and <newline> on his VKB, the name he has typed disappears because there are 2 lines in the window meant for 1.  I want the reflex <newline> to just activate the Ok response.

Comment: That's a desktop, not a mobile app. Normally you would just need request focus for the edit field and typing a character on a physical keyboard would start editing automatically.

Comment: It was more convenient to snap a desktop.  The codenameone screen is composed the same, based on Dialog.show

Comment: Is the VKB open at that stage? If so it would act in the exact same way as long as the text field has the focus.

Comment: Yes, its open, and no it doesn't.  For example, if I override the "setText" method of the textfield, I get a call for every character typed EXCEPT the newline.

Comment: You can probably use the done listener of the test field.

Comment: Something like that.  If this were to be integrated cleanly into the Dialog.show api, the middle window would be an ActionProvider, and the dialog should become an ActionListener

Comment: I don't see why that's related to dialog show. FYI it's our strong recommendation not to use text components in dialogs https://www.codenameone.com/blog/picking-dialog-type.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the behavior I want by making the text area an ActionListener.
Nothing was obvious about this.

```
    Command okCommand = null;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if(isSingleLineTextArea())  // only if we're a single line
    {
    if(okCommand!=null) // and we know what the ok command is.
    {   Form upd = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();      // get the current form
        upd.dispatchCommand(okCommand,new com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent(okCommand));
    }}
}
```